# Unknown Generic in C#

Tags: c#, variables, generics, interface, implements

I got the following Problem:

Is there a way to get all Classes that implement the IMatcher Interface in a List ?
The Generics T U cannot be set as Unknown. In Java we can use the "?", but in C# there is no Operator for this.

```
public interface IMatcher<T, U>
{
}

class X1: IMatcher<string, string>
{
} 

class X2: IMatcher<string, DateTime>
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<IMatcher<>> l = new List(); //NOT WORKING
        l.add(new X1());
        l.add(new X2());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Maybe you'll find your answer here: [Covariance and contravariance in generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) , but I think you may need a non-Generic base to actually do something useful with that.

Comment: You can only use a common base type, which in the case would be `object`. What are you trying to achieve? What would you do with this list? You would generally need to know the types to be able to use them in whatever the next step is.

Comment: From what I know, generics in Java and C# are totally different beasts.

Comment: You can always use `object` as a catch all in these scenarios - `new List<IMatcher<string, object>>();

Comment: This helps you to lookup the implementations for IMatcher<,>


var typeToFilter = typeof(IMatcher<,>);
            var impls = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetTypes().Cast<dynamic>()
                .Where(type => (type.ImplementedInterfaces as Type[]).Any(x => x.Name == typeToFilter.Name));

            foreach (var imp in impls)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(imp.Name);
            }

Comment: @phuzi that would only work if `U` was declared as covariant (i.e. `out U`). Whether it can be depends on how it's used, which we don't know.

Comment: Can you provide some of the methods `IMatcher` would have to implement?

Answer (score 1):

`IMatcher<string, string>` and `IMatcher<string, DateTime>` are as far as the compiler is concerned two different types. So there are no way to store X1 and X2 in the same list. Consider for example if the interface had a property `U MyProperty {get;set;}`, and you wanted to do `l[0].MyProperty` what should the type be? a string or a DateTime? Since it could be either it is simply not allowed.

One way to provide a workaround is to add a non-generic common interface, `public interface IMatcher {}` that `IMatcher<T, U>` derives from. Or a `IMatcher<T>`, since both X1 and X2 have the same T-parameter type.

You could possibly also use a `List<object>`, but then you lose the static typing. There is also `dynamic`, but that completely turns of type checking.

Answer (score 1):

You want "all Classes that implement the IMatcher Interface". But in fact, there is no `IMatchter` interface. There is only `IMatcher<T,U>`, which is to be precise not an interface. This notation is a shortcut, from which the compiler will be able to create a lot of different interfaces like `IMatcher<string,string>`, `IMatcher<string,DateTime>`, etc.

`IMatcher<string,string>` is a completely different type than `IMatcher<string,DateTime>`, hence `X1` and `X2` don't have a common base type! You need a common non-generic base type if you want to do that. It might look like this:

```
public interface IMatcher
{
    bool Match(object first, object second);
}

public interface IMatcher<T, U> : IMatcher
{
   bool Match(T first, U Second);
}

class X1: IMatcher<string, string>
{

   public bool Match(object first, object second)
   {
       return Match((string) first, (string) second);
   }

   public bool Match(string first, string second)
   {
       return true;
   }
} 

class X2: IMatcher<string, DateTime>
{
public bool Match(object first, object second)
   {
       return Match((string) first, (DateTime) second);
   }

   public bool Match(string first, DateTime second)
   {
       return true;
   }
}
```

Then you can store instances of `X1` and `X2` in common list, but you lose the advantages of generics. You have to decide if this approach makes sense in your case.

Comment: I think you want to edit the code so that `IMatcher<T, U> : IMatcher`

Answer (score -1):

Consider using the `dynamic` keyword if the generic types are **not** value types

Here is a simple example with a generic interface, 3 concrete implementations and a list to store them:

```
public interface IVector<out T>
{
    T[] Data { get; }
}

public class StrVector : IVector<string>
{
    public StrVector(params string[] data)
    {
        Data=data;
    }

    public string[] Data { get; }
}
public class IntVector : IVector<int>
{
    public IntVector(params int[] data)
    {
        Data=data;
    }

    public int[] Data { get; }
}
public class FileVector : IVector<FileInfo>
{
    public FileVector(params FileInfo[] data)
    {
        Data=data;
    }

    public FileInfo[] Data { get; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dynList = new List<IVector<dynamic>>();
        dynList.Add(new StrVector("a", "b", "c"));
        dynList.Add(new FileVector(new FileInfo("abc.txt"), new FileInfo("data.xml")));
        //dynList.Add(new IntVector(0, 5, 15, 80)); // Error: int is value type
        foreach (var item in dynList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", item.Data));
        }           
        //a,b,c
        //abc.txt,data.xml
     }
}
```